# Hide the link on Facebook post using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able  to post an image link to the Facebook from my Android app. But after posting, Facebook is displaying the link on top of the image. I don't want to display the link on top of the image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as app attribution. If your app is listed in the App Center (https://www.facebook.com/games/) the attribution will be visible. You can configure this in the `App Details` tab, under "App Center Listed Platforms".

If this doesn't solve your issues; can you provide your app ID, please?

Comment: My app is not available in the app center. Anyhow i got some fix. If we provide content url along with image url, facebook is not displaying the image url but content url, which is fine for me.